# GNU make: How to modify a file without re-executing rules?

Tags: c++, build, makefile, dependencies

Suppose I want to make an extremely minor (i.e. commenting, whitespace cleanup, etc) change to a file but I don't want Make to go through the time-consuming (>24hrs) rebuild process. Is there a way to do this?

I know you can do the opposite (i.e. rebuild without editing a file) using "touch", but that doesn't really help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do the opposite with `touch` as well.  One way I do it that's pretty easy is:

```
 $ cp -a foo.c foo.c.bak
 $ <fix up foo.c>
 $ touch foo.c -r foo.c.bak
```

Since `cp -a` should preserve the modification timestamp.  Another way something similar can be done is to note the modification timestamp (e.g. `stat -c "%y" foo.c` or something like that) and use the `-m` and `-t` arguments to `touch` instead of copying the file.

Comment: Looks like you and I came up with almost identical solutions. I will have to vote for this as 'useful'...

Comment: This seems like it will work, though I'm not currently on a Linux machine to test it. PS I often use gnu make on Windows as well... anybody know of the easiest Windows solution? All of the Win touch alternatives I see seem wordy/hackish/inelegant.

Answer (score 0):

After editing the file, you can change the "modification time" to whatever you want with

```
touch -m -r filename
```

Where `filename` is the name of a file with the time you want to copy (another untouched file from the build).  See http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utouch.htm

Answer (score 0):

touch is still the answer you just need to use it backwards.

1. Copy the file (preserving modification times, `-p`).
2. Edit the original file.
3. Use touch to reset the modification/etc. times back to what they were before (touch -r file.copy file).

That should be enough to do what you want.

And remember you can always ask make `-q` to see whether it thinks it will have any work to do to make sure you got it right.